# Why would @PostConstruct not work with Jetty + Apache MyFaces implementation?

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jetty

This is the code I have:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>
<build>
    <finalName>darbe</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>foo.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

foo.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and finally Foo.java

```
package biz.tugay;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        bar = "Hello World";
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

So here I am using the Oracle 's JSF implementation. And when I build this project and either deploy it to Tomcat or use the Jetty plugin(mvn jetty:start), I will see the text **Hello World** just fine on my browser.

However, when I change the dependencies as seen below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I will only see **Hello World** if I build the war file using maven and deploy it to Tomcat. When I run the application with mvn jetty:start, @PostConstruct will never be called, therefore foo.bar will be null.

What is going on here? How is an Annotation found in javax.annotation package processed / not processed based on the JSF implementation I choose AND the container I run the war file in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that myfaces ships out-of-the-box with built-in support for @PostConstruct/@PreDestroy with Tomcat and enables that by default.

If you look at your log trace when running with the jetty maven plugin you'll see:

> Jul 21, 2016 9:49:42 AM org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory getLifecycleProvider
>   INFO: Using LifecycleProvider org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider

So myfaces has found that Tomcat LifeCycleProvider baked into its impl jar, and uses it by default.

The solution is to tell myfaces explicitly to use a different LifeCycleProvider. I used the org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider (in the impl jar) and it appears to work, but may be worthwhile asking on the myfaces lists for more information. To set the LifeCycleProvider, add this to your web.xml:

```
          <context-param>
            <param-name>
              org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.LifecycleProvider
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
              org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.NoInjectionAnnotationLifecycleProvider
            </param-value>
          </context-param>
```